# Kubernetes: how to restart pods on memory or/and time limits?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to restart pods automatically after some time or when they reach some memory limit?

I want achieve the same behavior as gunicorn(or any mainstream process manager does)

Answer (score 9):

## Memory limit

If you set a limit for the memory on a container in the podTemplate, this pod will be restarted if it uses more than specified memory.

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 128Mi
```

See [Managing Compute Resources for Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/)
 for documentation

## Time limit

This can be done in many different ways, internally by calling `exit(1)` or stop responding on a configured [livenessProbe](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/). Or externally, e.g. by configuring a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/).